# Map on array of objects (Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'. TS2339)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, array.prototype.map

I'm doing an App where I fetch a list of Job Offers with the Recruitee API.
I stored the fetched Array in a state called jobs.

It looks something like this :

```
jobs = [ 0: {title: frontent-developer, company: whatever, departement: software}, 1: {title: fullstach-devloper, company: foobar, departement: management}]
```

Now I want to display it as a list with the help of the map function like this:

```
<ul>
{jobs.map((row) => {
                  return <li>(row.title)</li>;
                })}
</ul>
```

Now I get the error Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339 and I'm not sure what is wrong or what to do.

Does somebody got an idea?

Comment: The error indicates that the ```jobs``` is an object instead of an array.

Comment: When I console.log jobs:

(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 463154, slug: "frontend-developer-faro", position: 14, status: "published", options_phone: "required", …}
1: {id: 378427, slug: "individual-job-application", position: 5, status: "published", options_phone: "required", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Are you sure it complains about this map? maybe it's a different one in your code?

Comment: sadly the only map I'm using in my code :/

Comment: Can you show us how are you fetching the data and how you process it?

Comment: Please supply in your question the actual JSON response that you are processing... not "looks something like this" approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
const jobs = [
      {
        title: "frontent-developer",
        company: "whatever",
        departement: "software"
      },
      {
        title: "fullstach-devloper",
        company: "foobar",
        departement: "management"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <ul>
        {jobs.map((row) => {
          return <li>{row.title}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
```

Comment: Do you know how I can change the array into this format? 

I fetch the Data and json() it. I don't know how to get rid of the key

Answer (score 0):

I think this mistake in values try this.

```
let jobs = [{ 0: { title: " frontent - developer", company: "whatever",departement: "software" } }]

jobs.map((row, i) => {
return <li>(row[i].title)</li>;})
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @aum trivedi 's answer

This is incorrect json format :

```
  const  jobs = [ 0: {title: frontent-developer, company: whatever, departement: software}, 1: {title: fullstach-devloper, company: foobar, departement: management}]
```

Correct json format would be :

```
  const  jobs = [{ 0: {title: frontent-developer, company: whatever, departement: software}}, {1: {title: fullstach-devloper, company: foobar, departement: management}}]
```